# Step into Qt Sources from Qt Creator on Windows (NOT built from source)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, debugging, visual-c++

I have downloaded a binary build of Qt4 that is built for MSVC9/VS2008. I installed it from a setup file, I have NOT built it from source.

However, I do have the sources located at:

```
c:\QtSDK\QtSources\4.8.1\src:
```

I also have PDB files located at:

```
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\lib
```

So if I have both the PDBs and sources, I should be able to step into the source, even though I haven't built it from source.

**Note:** I've already found and read some questions asking how to step into Qt sources, however they are either [about Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049578/stepping-into-qt-sources-in-qt-creator-in-ubuntu-linux?rq=1) (that one's mine as well, actually), or [they don't specify whether it's compiled from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179482/debug-into-qt-sources) or not (a very important distinction).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I opened one of the PDB files - `c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\lib\QtCored4.pdb` - in a hex editor and found these strings describing file paths there:

```
c:\iwmake\build_vs2008_opensource_________________PADDING_________________\src\network\vc90.pdb
```

So I added a mapping using Tools->Options->Debugger->Add Qt Sources:

[image]

It's working and I can step into Qt Sources now :)

Keep in mind **the path might be different for you**, so you'll have to inspect your PDB files to find what to map.