# Stepping into Qt sources in Qt Creator (Fedora Linux) (Not built from source)

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, fedora

I'm attempting to step into Qt Source code to understand a particular warning I'm receiving. A lot of questions come close to answering this, most particularly this one:

[Stepping into Qt sources in Qt Creator (in Ubuntu Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049578/stepping-into-qt-sources-in-qt-creator-in-ubuntu-linux?rq=1)

Unfortunately this answer is for Ubuntu, and I have been unable to find the equivalent repository items mentioned in the answer in dnf on Fedora 29.

The answers to this ([Debug into Qt sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179482/debug-into-qt-sources?noredirect=1&lq=1)) question also seem relevant, except that:

- No file is named configure in any qt-related directories (perhaps this answer was for Qt4?)
- The method of including all source files is quite painful for a medium to large project.

Comment: For now, I'm going to attempt the alternate method of building Qt from source with the debug flag.

Comment: use `sudo dnf install qt5-qtbase qt5-qtbase-devel`. Others packages: `sudo dnf list qt5* `

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for the tip! I seem to already have this package, however. It seems that I am unable to step into qt functions as of yet.

Comment: Are you using Qt Creator?

Comment: @eyllanesc Sure am! Is this supposed to only work from command line gdb?

Comment: I do not understand you, gdb is a different tool, if you want to compile a project generated by Qt Creator from the terminal you should use qmake

Answer (score 1):

Download the official Qt online installer and select and install the Qt version you want to your home directory. Also make sure to install the source code of that Qt version. This will also install the official binary release of Qt Creator.

Using the official installer should give you an environment where you can debug and step into Qt code. The official Creator binary will also be set up automatically to work with the official Qt binaries by adding the necessary kits.